# WPF Fade out status bar text after X seconds?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

I'm trying to come up with an unobtrusive way to to display minor error messages to a user. So I've added a statusbar to my form,

```
    <StatusBar Margin="0,288,0,0" Name="statusBar" Height="23" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <TextBlock Name="statusText">Ready.</TextBlock>
    </StatusBar>
```

And then when they click an "Add" button, it should do some stuff, or display an error message:

```
private void DownloadButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    addressBar.Focus();
    var url = addressBar.Text.Trim();
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
    {
        statusText.Text = "Nothing to add.";
        return;
    }
    if (!url.Contains('.'))
    {
        statusText.Text = "Invalid URL format.";
        return;
    }
    if (!Regex.IsMatch(url, @"^\w://")) url = "http://" + url;
    addressBar.Text = "";
```

But the message just sits there for the life of the app... I think I should reset it after about 5 seconds... how can I set a timer to do that?

**Bonus:** How do I give it a nifty fade-out effect as I do so?

---

I've created a `System.Timers.Timer`,

```
    private Timer _resetStatusTimer = new Timer(5000);

    void _resetStatusTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        statusText.Text = "Ready";
    }
```

But the `Elapsed` event runs on a different thread than the UI, which it doesn't like... how to I get around that?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use a Storyboard to do the trick.

```
<Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard1">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="statusBarItem">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="1"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value="1"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:4" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
```

When the message has to be displayed you just call programmatically the Begin method of the StoryBoard or insert a trigger as below.

```
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TextBoxBase.TextChanged" SourceName="textBox">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Storyboard1}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
```

**EDIT:** Another option is to do like this:

```
<TextBlock Name="statusText" Text="{Binding Path=StatusBarText, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}">
        <TextBlock.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.TargetUpdated">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.25" Value="1"/>
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:4" Value="1"/>
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:5" Value="0"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </TextBlock.Triggers>
```

Then to create a DependencyProperty called StatusBarText in this case that is implemented as follow:

```
public string StatusBarText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(StatusBarTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StatusBarTextProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for StatusBarText.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty StatusBarTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("StatusBarText", typeof(string), typeof(MyOwnerClass), new UIPropertyMetadata(""));
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 8):

Your timer is a good approach, and you even identified your problem: you just need a way to access `statusText.Text` on the UI thread. (In WPF, threads other than the UI thread are prohibited from accessing UI elements). Here comes the WPF Dispatcher to the rescue:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx#S5

You can use the `DispatcherTimer` class to do exactly what you were attempting (here's their code):

```
// Create a Timer with a Normal Priority
_timer = new DispatcherTimer();

// Set the Interval to 2 seconds
_timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000); 

// Set the callback to just show the time ticking away
// NOTE: We are using a control so this has to run on 
// the UI thread
_timer.Tick += new EventHandler(delegate(object s, EventArgs a) 
{ 
    statusText.Text = string.Format(
        "Timer Ticked:  {0}ms", Environment.TickCount); 
});

// Start the timer
_timer.Start();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
await Task.Delay(5000); // Wait 5 seconds

for (int i = 99; i >= 0; i--)
{
    statusText.Opacity = i / 100d;

    await Task.Delay(15); // The animation will take 1.5 seconds
}

statusText.Visibility = statusText.Hidden;

statusText.Opacity = 1;
```

If you want to show `statusText` again, you have to sets it's `Visibility` to `Visible`:

```
statusText.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

Also make sure to add the `async` modifier to your methods signature, otherwise the compiler would show you an error relating the `await` operator. `await` is used that the UI still responds while the text is fading out.